# I sent btc from my wallet to my web site balance, deposit never showed

Tags: wallet-security

I have had hundreds of confirmations but the funding never made it from my wallet to the balance I was maintaining on a Web site (Alhabay). On blockchain the transaction is listed as "unspent." Where did my funds go? Can I get them back? I've been trying with zero success to get help from Alphabay.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I am seeing a few similar reports on reddit and people are speculating that they may be preparing an exit scam (where they accumulate as many Bitcoins as they can through fake "problems" and then disappear with everyone's money). It's also possible that some of those people are lying or that it's just a minor technical problem. You never know with sites like those.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. AlphaBay's Help Desk is filled with issues identical to mine :(. Bad feeling.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to contact the site, Alhabay, for support. This is your only way. The bitcoins have been sent and confirmed on the blockchain, and they are in Alhabay's possession right now.

Bitcoin is like cash. It's irreversible. Once you've gave someone cash, they have it and the only way you can get it back is if they give it back to you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I've been trying to contact Alphabay via their help desk forum for a week :(.

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoins delivered but something is not ok with their wallet they might need resetting block chains and peer depending upon their wallet client app.